# Compilation and Linking in C++

Tags: c++, linker, compilation

I am looking for a detailed article about compilation and linking in c++. I know a lot about them, but sure there are some subtle points I missed.

Comment: Some of them might be vendor- or platform specific, do you have any particular one in mind?

Comment: @Christian.K I would like to read some theory plus some (if there are) platform or vendor specific cases (windows, unix),(cl, g++)

Comment: What does "a lot" mean? Have you written/built a portable C++ Wrapper using different assembler code for specific platforms? Have you heard a CS curse like "Programming Languages and Compilers" or "Compiler Building"?

Comment: "a lot" mean "Yes!" to your both questions.

Comment: I would check http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/gcc/ for what the full knowledge may look like and then decide whether or not I need to know so much.

Answer (score 6):

[Linkers and Loaders](http://www.iecc.com/linker/) is a classic for that topic. The theoretical background for Compilers is given in [Dragon Book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools#Second_edition). If you really want build a Compiler [Let's Build a Compiler](http://compilers.iecc.com/crenshaw/) is worth reading. There where some courses on Compilers recorded on video mentioned in this Stackoverflow Question: [Are there any compiler lectures available via video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424796/are-there-any-compiler-lectures-available-via-video)

A very short overview for C++ is given [here](http://www.tenouk.com/ModuleW.html). I guess, most of that you'll already know.

If you're really into it, how about reading the sources from different versions of gcc and llvm/clang? The Sun/Oracle [Linker and Libraries Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19253-01/817-1984/) offers a comprehensive work specific for the Sun/Solaris platform.

Comment: An excellent book, but due to its publication date, it only touches on many of the issues of C++ linking (templates, in particular).  The short overview is specific to one particular implementation.

Comment: @mbx: "some curses on Compilers" --> I do curse gcc a lot.

Comment: @mbx: sure made me laugh :D I could already picture "webcam shots" of developpers getting frustrating at gcc and turning into frenzied monsters foaming at the mouth...

Answer (score 3):

I liked this [series](http://www.airs.com/blog/index.php?s=Linkers&paged=5) by Ian Lance Taylor (Author of the [gold](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Gold_%28linker%29) linker). It explains linkers and their history in great detail.

Answer (score 1):

There is a a paper called [how tow write shared libraries](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) by Ulrich Drepper. It is not the linker itself but it explains very deeply how symbols loading and resolution works, thing that is related. It is only Linux oriented by the way.